# How to force maven to download a artifact from a specific repo in plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, pom.xml, parent, checkstyle

I am trying solve an issue related with download of my own checktyle from the plugin section in my pom.xml.
At the moment the pom.xml contains all necessary configurations that allows me to download the dependencies from my own artifactory. The problem occurs when I am trying to download a specific artifact of my jar file, every time I try, the code tries to download from the maven central instead of going to my configurations of repos added into the pom.

**How can I "force" the plugin to check in my artifactory first instead of going all the time to the maven central repository? There is any specific configurations for the plugins?**

The code that I have to download my own artifact in the plugins is the one below.
I am pointing already the repository via DistributionManagement and repositories.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            ....
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.test.checkstyle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstle-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>8.31</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <configLocation>build/checkstyle-test.xml</configLocation>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory</sourceDirectory>                    
                   <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
              ...
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Note:
I am to have a clean settings.xml with all necessary configurations, I won't be able to manage the settings.xml after I deploy the application.

Comment: There is a typo in `<artifactId>checkstle-tools`.

Comment: Did you add a `<repositories>` or `<pluginRepositories>` in your case? That should do the trick: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Repositories . If you also need to _force_ maven to not go over central, you'll need a settings however.

Comment: there is no typo error @Gerold Broser

Comment: I have the repositories in my code and I can get all dependencies from that :) the problem is when I am trying to download the artifact from the plugin

Comment: There is bad naming in `<artifactId>checkstle-tools`. What do you mean by "_download a specific artifact of my jar file_"? Artifacts _are_ JAR files (most of the time). Please add your repo config to your question (`settings.xml` and `pom.xml`). Please add the error msg to your question.

Comment: @user3658886 as strange as it may be, for plugin's dependencies, what is important is *not* `<repositories>` but `<pluginRepositories>`. Also, when you test, be sure to remove the local folder (eg: `$HOME/.m2/repository/com/test/checkstyle/checkstyle-tools`) or try with -U. This may affect dependency resolution as well.